Python type hint for returning one of two different tuples
I'm working with legacy code which returns a single tuple, but with changes will return the original tuple, or another tuple with an additional value. Basically like this:
1  #!/usr/bin/python
2  from typing import Union
3
4  def func(x):
5      # type: (bool) -> Union[tuple[str, int], tuple[str, str, int]]
6      if x:
7          return "one", "two", 0
8      return "one", 0
9
10  one, two = func(False)
11  print(f"{one} {two}")
12  one, two, three = func(True)
13  print(f"{one} {two} {three}")

The code works as expected:
$ ./tt.py
one 0
one two 0

But when I run mypy on it, I get:
$ mypy tt.py
tt.py:10: error: Too many values to unpack (2 expected, 3 provided)  [misc]
tt.py:12: error: Need more than 2 values to unpack (3 expected)  [misc]
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

Am I missing something or is this an issue with mypy?

Please don't post code with line numbers. It makes it difficult to copy and paste the code to run it.

Mypy gives you an error because the function can return two or three items. Mypy does not infer that it will be three items if the input is True.
You might be looking for overloads. That way, you can type that the output will be a tuple with three items if the input is True or two items if the input is False. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#overload for more info about overloads.
If you go with overloads, however, it appears that it would need to accept a literal True or False. It's not possible at the moment to type "truthy" of "falsey" values (i.e., values that would be coerced to a True or False).
Sticking with your current code, you could add an if statement to check the length of the returned tuple. That will probably satisfy mypy.

It's interesting that it errors on both lines, regardless if how many items would actually be returned.  I will look into overloads, thanks.

Because both lines are an error. x, y = ... requires exactly two values, and x, y, z = ... requires exactly 3 values. The return type doesn't provide either guarantee. Hardcoding the argument doesn't let mypy make the kind of assumption you want.
